# Callback to confirm that "SRC" attribute is set in IFRame

Tags: jquery, iframe, load, jquery-callback, jquery-attributes

Need to show the popup only when the data is loaded inside IFrame successfully.
Currently popup gets visible even if the source of IFrame doesn't get loaded.
Here is the code snippet:

```
$('#myIframe').attr('src', 'Student.aspx?roll=' + rollNumber);
$('#studentInfoPopup').modal('show');
```

I tried with the following, but it didn't work:

```
$("#myIframe").load(function(){
      $('#studentInfoPopup').modal('show');
}).attr('src', 'Student.aspx?roll=' + rollNumber);
```

Kindly let me know the callback to confirm that "SRC" attribute is set in IFrame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **jQuery** as below::

```
$('#myIframe').attr('src', 'Student.aspx?roll=' + rollNumber);
$('#myIframe').load(function(){
  $('#studentInfoPopup').modal('show');
});
```

**UPDATED:**
I have done this in **JSFIDDLE**, please check the link it will help you. and modify it as your need. Link: https://jsfiddle.net/a1kj8883/

Comment: Thanks Rana for your quick reply.

But, it is opening a modal popup without any data.
Kindly help me out.

Comment: please upvote and accept the answer if it helped you to helping others.

Comment: Done.. 
Need one more help.. 
Kindly check the following : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43125196/show-a-bootstrap-popup-and-then-revert-the-eventdrop-in-fullcalendar-based-on-us