# Show a Bootstrap popup and then revert the eventDrop in FullCalendar based on user's choice

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar, dom-events

Currently I am using Javascript confirm box to ask whether the user wants to proceed or he wants to revert, but I need to warn the user using Bootstrap popup.
User needs to say 'Proceed/Cancel' in popup.

I used bootstrap modal popup. but the 'drop' doesn't wait for user's choice.
**It executes the flow of code written inside 'eventDrop', before user clicks yes/no button of popup.**

Current code snippet:

```
eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
        if (!confirm("Are you sure to re-book the ticket?"))
            revertFunc();
}
```

Kindly suggest.

Comment: Is it solved yet?

Comment: Please add it in jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes in `eventDrop` function `if` not work if `{` `}` not given. So, please follow my code below::

```
eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
    if (!confirm("Are you sure to re-book the ticket?")) {
      revertFunc();
    }
}
```

But it will be better to use a **confirmbox** or **bootstap cofirm modal** because if any user checks *prevent this page from additional dialogs* , from next time that alert box will not show.

Working url:: https://jsfiddle.net/rekdp2wt/

Comment: That was my initial request..

The functionality had worked with "Javascript-ConfirmBox" for me as well,
but I need to make it work with a bootstrap-popup.

The issue i am facing is, the code written in 'eventDrop' event doesn't wait for the yes/no from the user.

    eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
        $('#confirmPopup').modal('show');
        //revertFunc();
    }

It shows a popup with a message and two buttons viz. 'Proceed/Cancel'. But the problem is where and how to call 'revertFunc()' function, if user clicks on 'Cancel' button of bootstarp-popup.